# Duplicate Symbol _winSocks in XCODE

Tags: xcode

i am having an error as duplicate symbol _winsocks in /users/..../xxx.o  and /users/..../yyy.o

can any one tell me how to avoid this error in XCODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about XCODE specifically, but this sort of  error means that both object files define the the `__winsocks` symbol (which means they were compiled with something (maybe a header file) that defines this. If you can provide the compile/link instructions for each of them, then maybe we can give you more help.